# Starting w/Python3 - Where would i place pip3 install requests here?

Tags: python

```
import urllib.request 
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
   html = response.read()
print (html)
```

# I am trying to learn how to access the internet, having a little trouble in any way I go about it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking. What does "where would I place pip3 install requests" mean? Are you asking how to install the `requests` library? How to import it into your program? Please read [ask] for tips on asking effective questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pip3 is a command you can run in your terminal or shell.

Just run this in your terminal to obtain the requests package.

> pip3 install requests

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, you would place `pip3 install requests` in the command prompt. If you are on a mac, then put it in the terminal. If you are using Linux, use the Linux terminal. This will install the requests library. Then you can import the requests library in your code.